# Expression conversion error using generic repository on MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, expression, func

i'm having some trouble on making a generic mongodb repository
(i've collection made as GenericRepositoryEntry)

```
 public static void SaveRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>(
        TDataObject msg,
        Func<GenericRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>, bool> finder01,
        Expression<Func<GenericRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>, bool>> finder02,
        Func<GenericRepositoryEntry<DataValue>, bool> finder03,
        Expression<Func<GenericRepositoryEntry<DataValue>, bool>> finder04)
        where TDataObject : DataValue
    { 
            using (var ctx = new MongoContext())
            {
                IMongoQueryable<GenericRepositoryEntry<DataValue>> iQuery = ctx.DataValues.AsQueryable();

                var items01 = iQuery.Where(x => finder01(x)).ToList(); //compile error
                var items02 = iQuery.Where(finder02).ToList(); //compile error
                var items03 = iQuery.Where(x => finder03(x)).ToList();
                var items04 = iQuery.Where(finder04).ToList();
            }
    }
```

this is the repo collection class

```
 public class GenericRepositoryEntry<T>
 {
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public T DataObject { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
    public bool ActualFlag { get; set; }
 }
```

**items01:**

```
cannot convert from 'GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.MongoEntry.GenericRepositoryEntry<GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.Ocpp.DataValue>' to 'GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.MongoEntry.GenericRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>'
```

**items02:**

```
 cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.MongoEntry.GenericRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>, bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.MongoEntry.GenericRepositoryEntry<GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.Ocpp.DataValue>, int, bool>>'
```

**items03 and items04**

are ok... because i don't use generic type :(

i receive compile error  on items01/items02
looks like it's ignoring - `where TDataObject : DataValue`

also trying to change SaveRepositoryEntry method signature as

```
where TDataObject : IMongoEntryDataItem
```

and changing repoEntryClass

`public class GenericRepositoryEntry<T>
        where T: IMongoEntryDataItem`

Comment: It will not ignore the constraint, but your question is incomplete, provide more details. How are you calling the generic function, what is the base class, these are compile time issues, which are seen moment you try to call the function

Comment: You have reverted the changes I made to fix your formatting, please do them again, they are important because of the `<` characters.

Comment: Can you post the line, which shows compilation error, that is calling the function `SaveRepositoryEntry<TDataObject>`, as I can see from the error you pass `GlobalElectricGateway.Core.Model.Ocpp.DataValue` as `TDataObject`, which has constraint but compiler doesn't think you are referring to same class, why not fully quality the constraint too

Comment: i still have no caller!
compilation error is on
 var items01 = iQuery.Where(x => finder01(x)).ToList(); //compile error
                var items02 = iQuery.Where(finder02).ToList(); //compile error
(errors are written in main post)